# How can I install the php memcached extension on Docker's PHP7 Alpine image?

Tags: php, docker, memcached, dockerfile, pecl

The official php7 docker image has the following example:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

I'm trying to use `FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine`:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache libmemcached-dev
RUN      pecl install memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

PECL gives this error:

> pecl/memcached requires PHP (version >= 5.2.0, version <= 6.0.0,
>   excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is 7.0.13

How can I install the memcached php extension on alpine?

Comment: I believe I figured it out, will post instructions when I confirm it's working and have time to update here.

Answer (score 30):

Currently the [php-memcached-dev:php7](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/tree/php7) branch contains the source for this extension.

To install it you can still use the `docker-php-ext-*` commands but you need to checkout the source yourself.

### Base Installation

Assuming everything required to install the extension is already installed you can do:

```
RUN git clone -b php7 https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-configure /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
        --disable-memcached-sasl \
    && docker-php-ext-install /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/php/ext/memcached
```

This block will clone the repository, configure and install the extension then clean up after it self.

### Pre-requisites

It is most likely that you need to install to packages to build the extension, we can add and remove them by doing:

```
ENV MEMCACHED_DEPS zlib-dev libmemcached-dev cyrus-sasl-dev git
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache libmemcached-libs zlib \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        --virtual .memcached-deps \
        $MEMCACHED_DEPS \
    && git clone -b php7 https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-configure /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
        --disable-memcached-sasl \
    && docker-php-ext-install /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && apk del .memcached-deps
```

---

**Update 17 May 2017**

`memcached` has been added to the official pecl libraries for php7 now (v3 -> php7/7.1, v2 -> php5)

This makes installation a bit different

```
FROM php:7.0-alpine

ENV MEMCACHED_DEPS zlib-dev libmemcached-dev cyrus-sasl-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --update libmemcached-libs zlib
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .memcached-deps $MEMCACHED_DEPS \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && echo "extension=memcached.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20_memcached.ini \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/php7 \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && apk del .memcached-deps .phpize-deps
```

Comment: I've been looking for hours now to install php memcached. Your steps do not throw any errors but after installing I get the folowing error; `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/memcached.so' - Error loading shared library libmemcached.so.11: No su
ch file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/memcached.so) in Unknown on line 0` How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue is that libmemcached-dev is added as virtual dependency and removed afterwards. You have to add libmemcached library separately. So just add `apk add --update libmemcached` just below `set -xe`. @harry-bragg please update your answer. It was very helpful for me

Comment: A few things have changed since I made this post, I will update it with how I am current doing things

Comment: @HarryBragg, what is the ```set -xe``` for?

Comment: @Sebastian Bit late maybe but... "`-x` Print a trace of simple commands. `-e` Exit immediately if a command returns a non-zero status." [See also the manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html). You can just google 'man <command you want to learn more about>' for most of these things. Or even just in shell/cli on a unix system do 'man <command>' to get relevant info.

Comment: @HarryBragg I see `-dev ` postfix on name of the package? 
`zlib-dev` `libmemcached-dev` `cyrus-sasl-dev`
I assume it development a not a stable version of the package is that so?

Answer (score 24):

Try it.

```
FROM php:7.2.10-fpm-alpine3.7


# Install PHP Extensions (igbinary & memcached)
RUN apk add --no-cache --update libmemcached-libs zlib
RUN set -xe && \
    cd /tmp/ && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .memcached-deps zlib-dev libmemcached-dev cyrus-sasl-dev && \
# Install igbinary (memcached's deps)
    pecl install igbinary && \
# Install memcached
    ( \
        pecl install --nobuild memcached && \
        cd "$(pecl config-get temp_dir)/memcached" && \
        phpize && \
        ./configure --enable-memcached-igbinary && \
        make -j$(nproc) && \
        make install && \
        cd /tmp/ \
    ) && \
# Enable PHP extensions
    docker-php-ext-enable igbinary memcached && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    apk del .memcached-deps .phpize-deps
```

Comment: Top! Still working in 2021, solved my problem. Thanksalot!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Debian 11

```
FROM php:7.4.28-apache
RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && \
    apt-get install -y memcached libmemcached-tools && \
    pecl install memcached && \
    docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

And you can start the daemon using something like this:

/etc/init.d/memcached start