# Install php7-gd in alpine

Tags: php, gd, alpine-linux

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli 
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/" >>         /etc/apk/repositories &&
apk update && \
apk upgrade && \
apk add --update \
    php7-gd
```

mysqli is ok, but it does not load GD library.

I also find gd.so in alpine container, please check the image:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 37):

You should not mix Alpine Linux 3.4, Alpine Linux edge and PHP compiled from source.

## Solution 1

Use the official latest release of Alpine Linux

```
FROM alpine:3.5
```

and add

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/3.5/community
```

then install memcache using pecl (in php7-pear).

## Solution 2

Use the docker-php-ext-install script to add gd

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev
```

For more image support you can also apk add and del:

```
libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev libxpm-dev
```

I left the answer using the official Alpine Linux on top, since we should always try to use official docker repos. But currently the second solution is better.

The second solution was provided by ncopa at the Alpine Linux IRC channel. Thanks.

Comment: it is working for me now. but I face new issue, cannot install php memcache on alpine

Comment: Well, I don't use PHP, but it looks like you could use the pecl tool to install memcache. You'd probably need the packages php7-pear, php7-dev and alpine-sdk. http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.installation.php.

Comment: @anhduc.bkhn This might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894385/how-can-i-install-the-php-memcached-extension-on-dockers-php7-alpine-image