# How to add php gd extension to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, php-extension, alpine-linux, php-gd

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy using alpine:

```
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.2.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add zlib-dev gd php7-gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets pdo_mysql zip
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd
```

The error is an output from a jenkins run. I think it's failing somewhere around here...

```
build:
    docker run --rm --tty --user $$(id -u):$$(id -g) \
        --volume "$$(pwd)":/app \
        --volume "$$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/github.token":/tmp/auth.json \
        --volume "$$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/composer_trust_github.com":/root/.ssh/config \
        composer install --no-dev
    rm -rf ops/docker/app.tar.gz
    tar -czvf ops/docker/app.tar.gz -X ops/jenkins/build_excludes .

docker run --rm --tty --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    --volume "$(pwd)":/app \
    --volume "$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/github.token":/tmp/auth.json \
    --volume "$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/composer_trust_github.com":/root/.ssh/config \
    --volume "$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/php/php.ini":/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    composer install --no-dev
[32mLoading composer repositories with package information[39m
[32mInstalling dependencies from lock file[39m
[37;41mYour requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.[39;49m

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.2.1 -&gt; satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.2.1].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.2.1 requires ext-gd * -&gt; the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
```

How do I correctly add ext-gd?

---

**UPDATE: More information**

The commands of the Makefile which Jenkins calls in order are as follows:

```
prepare:
    git clone git@github.com:xxx/go-php-sqs-consumer
    cd go-php-sqs-consumer && glide install
    docker run --rm -v "${PWD}/go-php-sqs-consumer":/go/src/app -w /go/src/app golang:1.8.1-alpine go build -o consumer
    mv go-php-sqs-consumer/consumer ops/docker/consumer
    rm -rf go-php-sqs-consumer

build:
    echo "{\"github-oauth\":{\"github.com\":\"$$(credstash get github.tech-craft.jenkins-eu-west-1)\"}}" > ops/jenkins/github.token
    docker run --rm --tty --user $$(id -u):$$(id -g) \
        --volume "$$(pwd)":/app \
        --volume "$$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/github.token":/tmp/auth.json \
        --volume "$$(pwd)/ops/jenkins/composer_trust_github.com":/root/.ssh/config \
        composer install --no-dev
    rm -rf ops/docker/app.tar.gz
    ansible-vault decrypt config.*.json && chmod a+r config.*.json
    tar -czvf ops/docker/app.tar.gz -X ops/jenkins/build_excludes .

archive:
    aws s3api put-object --bucket craft-build --key "auth-api/${s3_key_version}.tar.gz" --body "ops/docker/app.tar.gz"
    aws s3api put-object --bucket craft-build --key "auth-api/current.tar.gz" --body "ops/docker/app.tar.gz"

containerise:
    cd ops/docker && docker build --pull --no-cache -t application-exporter-service .
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct image? Just created `Dockerfile` locally (exactly as yours) and added composer to it. `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` installs without any issues.

Comment: See my update. I don't know if that makes more sense. I don't know how `docker run` is even working without defining an image to actually run. This is a colleagues code who has run off and left me alone to handle. The tutorials I've seen, `docker run` normally follows with something like `.. nginx:latest`.

Comment: It works exactly as expected. The `docker run` uses a `composer` image and executes an `install --no-dev` command inside it. Then it packs everything as a tar archive (for release, I guess). Try to change the command to `install --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts`

Answer (score 21):

Here's how I do it but on `php` image, not `alpine`. Maybe you can just "finetune" it to work on alpine:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: php:7.3-fpm gives me a error: libpng12-dev is not found, maybe you can adjust your answer

Comment: you can use `libpng-dev` instead of `libpng12-dev`

Comment: In my case (image `php:7.1-apache`) `libpng-dev' is mandatory, otherwise: `E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 9):

[It's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087734/install-php7-gd-in-alpine) help for me:

```
RUN apk update

RUN apk add libpng libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev libxpm-dev gd && docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Izydorr. In addition to that, you could also create your own docker registry and modify a small baseimage for your needs and use it as a build image for jenkins.