# Docker with laravel fails because of php extension

Tags: php, laravel, docker

**Running `Laravel` on an `appache` server.**

Upon building the image with `docker-compose up --build` with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd

FROM composer:1.9.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo && composer install
```

I am getting the error message:

```
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.13.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
```

This happens when the `composer install` command runs.

As you can see up, I am actually installing gd from php, so it should not give me this error message.

Do you have any idea how I can solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002052/965834) (Not marking it as dupe as I'm unsure it's the same scenario, looks close though.)

Comment: No it doesn't work. Similar error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happen, because you are using multistage building and your `composer` second stage have nothing to do with previous build using `PHP` container. Primary use case with multistaging is to produce some useful artefacts which can be used later.

So what I suggest is to copy composer file from `composer` image, then place it somewhere in your `php` container.

I will give you my solution which is working perfectly for me with **laravel/symfony** etc.

```
FROM php:7.4.4-fpm

# We copy composer from it's original image to our php container to use it later.
COPY --from=composer:1.9 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www

ARG USER_ID

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/user/ -m -G sudo,www-data user -u $USER_ID

RUN apt update && apt install -y zip unzip wget zlib1g-dev libicu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql intl opcache gd

USER user

RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash

ENV PATH="/home/user/.symfony/bin:${PATH}"

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

# You can also run here composer install, depends on your use case
```

Comment: So what you would suggest us to copy composer as you did, and then simply `RUN composer install` and this should work?

Comment: Exactly, but you have to be sure, that you put your composer file to bin directory, where commands can be globally evaluated by your shell.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. It was really helpful to see my conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your docker image. For example try this:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
WORKDIR /app
RUN php ./artisan config:cache && composer install
```