# PHP Dockerfile with php-memcached not working

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, memcached

I can't build any image with PHP-Memcached extension. All they give me an error messages and how many times I try it's not helpful. I can't even find any PHP Dockerfile which include memcached and it's work. Even the main [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) of PHP docker page have Dockerfile with PHP Memcached solution and it's also not working.

```
FROM php:5.6-cli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev \

&& pecl install memcached-2.2.0 \

&& docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

Here is my last try code

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# for mysqli if you want
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && \
    pecl install memcached && \
    docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

Who knows about this something? Thanks, advice

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894385/how-can-i-install-the-php-memcached-extension-on-dockers-php7-alpine-image helps, it seems to start from the same point you are at.

Comment: @NigelRen yes that was helpful. You save my day really appreciate it. Honestly, I found that link but not run Dockerfile cause it's using another image than mine. But now I will use that image anyway. There is no solution with php:7.4-fpm docker image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install the php memcached extension on Docker's PHP7 Alpine image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894385/how-can-i-install-the-php-memcached-extension-on-dockers-php7-alpine-image)

Comment: @Marcinek yes but need to use another image to build. With `php:7.4-fpm` yet no solution. I think the answer of my question is hiding in params `--no-cache --update`.

Comment: @Marcinek look at my answer below. There is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution on my problem at last and it's connected with /etc/apt/source.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

And then just add this `COPY ./sources.list /etc/apt/sourcee.list` line in your Dockerfile and it will work

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

COPY ./sources.list /etc/apt/sourcee.list
```

Answer (score 0):

I have separated memcached and phm-memcached. The first one is a container, and second is installed on Dockerfile for PHP.
My docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:
    # PHP
    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php7-fpm
        volumes:
        // etc...

    memcached:
        image: memcached:latest
        hostname: memcached
        networks:
            - stack
```

And in my Dockerfile for PHP:

```
FROM php:7-4-fpm

// install dependencies...

# php-memcached
RUN set -ex \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && MEMCACHED="`mktemp -d`" \
    && curl -skL https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/master.tar.gz | tar zxf - --strip-components 1 -C $MEMCACHED \
    && docker-php-ext-configure $MEMCACHED \
    && docker-php-ext-install $MEMCACHED \
    && rm -rf $MEMCACHED
```

And with this, in my symfony application, i can store data in memcached.